# Fechando tag PHP aparecendo na pagina

Tags: php

Estou usando arquivo **.php** mas quando tento acessar o site ele aparece `?>` no topo da página e já verifiquei, não possui nenhuma tag sem fechar ou algo do gênero.

```php
<?php 
session_start();
    include("conecta.php");
    $pega_id = $_SESSION['usuario'];
  $busca_id= "SELECT id FROM cadastro WHERE usuario = '$pega_id' ";
    $resultado_id = mysqli_query($conn, $busca_id);
        while($row_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_id)){
            $id = $row_id['id'];
        }
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Notas Fundamental</title> <!-- Título da página -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--Serve para colocar acentuações na página -->
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/exposoft.css" /> <!-- Linkando o css -->


    <!-- Inserindo JavaScript na página -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se o problema não está nessa página, o mais provavel é que esteja no arquivo `conecta.php`